# Change an HTML table's values when a dropdown is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

How can I make my HTML table update when someone changes a dropdown to a different value?

I have a pricing table for domain name registrations and I want the user to be able to select how many years they would like to register a domain name from a drop down and the table's prices update.

Any resources or suggestions is greatly appreciated!

```html
<div class="domain-pricing-block">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="domain-pricing-head">
   <h3>Domain Pricing</h3>
   <p>Includes DNS Management and Domain Forwarding</p>
  </div><!--domain-pricing-head-->
  <div class="domain-pricing-table">
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <div class="table">
     <table class="table">
      <tr>
       <th>TLD</th>
       <th>Register</th>
       <th>Transfer</th>
       <th>Renew</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>.com</td>
       <td>$14.95 USD</td>
       <td>$14.95 USD</td>
       <td>$14.95 USD</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>.net</td>
       <td>$14.95 USD</td>
       <td>$14.95 USD</td>
       <td>$14.95 USD</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>.org</td>
       <td>$14.95 USD</td>
       <td>$14.95 USD</td>
       <td>$14.95 USD</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>.biz</td>
       <td>$14.95 USD</td>
       <td>$14.95 USD</td>
       <td>$14.95 USD</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div><!--domain-pricing-table-->
  <div class="domain-price-type">
   <ul>
    <li>
     <label>Registration Period:</label>
     <div class="box">
      <select class="wide">
       <option value="1">1 Year</option>
       <option value="2">2 Years</option>
       <option value="3">3 Years</option>
       <option value="4">4 Years</option>
      </select>
     </div><!--domain-ext-->
    </li>
    <li>
     <input type="button" class="dom-go" value="Go">
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div><!--domain-price-type-->
 </div>
</div><!--domain-pricing-block-->
```

I've provided a screenshot of the table as well:

[image: View Screenshot of Table]

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Detecting the select change? Updating the table? You haven't indicated where the new values come from.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't given us much to work with I'm going to work with a fixed formula.

The base price is stored against the table cell as a data attribute. A price modifier is stored against the select options in a similar manner. On select change, the table cell is updated on `price x period x modifier`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
//Cache the Table Cells
    var priceTableCells = $(".domain-pricing-table table td[data-base]");
    /*console.log(priceTableCells);*/

//Event Handler For Select Change
    $("#registrationPeriod").change(function(){
      var period = parseFloat($(this).val());
      var modifier = $(this).find(":selected").data("modifier");     
      
      //Iterate cells and update them
      $(priceTableCells).each(function(){
        var base = $(this).data("base");
        $(this).text("$" +(base * period * modifier).toFixed(2) + " USD");
      });    
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="domain-pricing-block">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="domain-pricing-head">
   <h3>Domain Pricing</h3>
   <p>Includes DNS Management and Domain Forwarding</p>
  </div><!--domain-pricing-head-->
  <div class="domain-pricing-table">
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <div class="table">
     <table class="table">
      <tr>
       <th>TLD</th>
       <th>Register</th>
       <th>Transfer</th>
       <th>Renew</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>.com</td>
       <td data-base="14.95">$14.95 USD</td>
       <td data-base="14.95">$14.95 USD</td>
       <td data-base="14.95">$14.95 USD</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>.net</td>
       <td data-base="14.95">$14.95 USD</td>
       <td data-base="14.95">$14.95 USD</td>
       <td data-base="14.95">$14.95 USD</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>.org</td>
       <td data-base="14.95">$14.95 USD</td>
       <td data-base="14.95">$14.95 USD</td>
       <td data-base="14.95">$14.95 USD</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>.biz</td>
       <td data-base="14.95">$14.95 USD</td>
       <td data-base="14.95">$14.95 USD</td>
       <td data-base="14.95">$14.95 USD</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div><!--domain-pricing-table-->
  <div class="domain-price-type">
   <ul>
    <li>
     <label>Registration Period:</label>
     <div class="box">
      <select class="wide" id="registrationPeriod">
       <option value="1" data-modifier="1">1 Year</option>
       <option value="2" data-modifier="0.9">2 Years</option>
       <option value="3" data-modifier="0.8">3 Years</option>
       <option value="4" data-modifier="0.75">4 Years</option>
      </select>
     </div><!--domain-ext-->
    </li>
    <li>
     <input type="button" class="dom-go" value="Go">
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div><!--domain-price-type-->
 </div>
</div><!--domain-pricing-block-->
```